# cant update SQLite data base query

Tags: android, sqlite

I got a problem with trying to update a query in SQLite in android studio.

I have this array of followers and I transform it to a string with space separating every item in the list, so next time that I will want to retrieve the list back it will be easy to change it back to an actual array list again.

I tried following the android developers tutorial and my teacher's tutorial and it still gives me the error message.

here's my code:

```
    public static void updateFollowersArray(SQLiteDatabase db, UserClass user) {

    String where = USER_TABLE_USER_NAME + " = ?";
    String[] args = {user.get_userName()};

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();


    ArrayList<String> tempFollowersArray = user.getFollowersArray();

    String tempFollowersString = new String();
    if(tempFollowersArray!=null){
        for (String follower : tempFollowersArray) {
            tempFollowersString += follower + " ";
        }
    }

    values.put(USER_TABLE_FOLLOWERS_ARRAY, tempFollowersString);

    if (db.update(USER_TABLE, values, where, args) < 1) {
        Log.e("updateSQLfollowersArray", "FAILED");
    } else
        Log.e("updateSQLfollowersArray", "SUCCEED");
}
```

Comment: Where's the error? Seriously, how do you suppose we should give any answer?

Comment: sorry for not being more clear about it, I thought it was good enough. after I perform the  "db.update(USER_TABLE, values, where, args", it return an answer which is < 1, which means it doesn't updating my query, and because it gives back an answer which is < 1, the if command I put gives me an error message in Log as you can see.

Comment: so I don't understand why it failes everytime I try to update my query

Comment: Sounds like it's just not finding any matching results. Have you checked that the table USER_TABLE_FOLLOWERS_ARRAY exists, that the column USER_TABLE_USER_NAME exists and that user.get_userName() returns the expected value?

Comment: stupid as im gonna sound, that was my problem. I hadn't any users in my users table so that  it could find what I was looking for.